# how can I add different character to blank spaces in a string?(or replace specific word in a string with different characters or numbers.)

Tags: python, string, replace, text-manipulation

how can I add characters/numbers to blank spaces like this:

```
Today the ---- is cloudy, but there is no ----.

Today the --a)-- is cloudy, but there is no --b)--.(desired result)
```

As you can see blank spaces are not replaced with a fixed character, which makes using python `replace()` method complicated for me.

Comment: You're not replacing blank spaces, you're replacing a string of hyphens.

Comment: you can use for loop and if statement to do that

Comment: Strings are immutable, so you need to create new ones.  Perhaps you can simply use f-strings: `a = "--a)--"; b = "--b)--"; f"Today the {a} is cloudy, but there is no {b}."`

Comment: Is it always sequential letters, `a`, `b`, `c`, etc.?

Comment: @Alexander Presumably the string to modify is dynamic, not a literal.

Comment: @Barmar actually, it was blank spaces which I replaced them with "----", then I stock to trouble for finding a solution to reach to the desired result.

Comment: @Barmar yes, there would be always sequential letters, as you mentioned.

Comment: But what about the blank spaces between `Today` and `the`, between `is` and `cloudy`, etc? Why aren't you replacing them? What is the actual pattern?

Comment: @Barmar those spaces are not my concern, imagine fill in the blank quiz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `re.sub()`. It allows you to use a function as the replacement, so the function can increment the character each time it's called. I've written the function as a generator.

```
import re

def next_char():
    char = 'a'
    while True:
        yield char
        char = chr(ord(char) + 1)
        if char > 'z':
            char = 'a'

seq = next_char()

str = 'Today the ---- is cloudy, but there is no ----.'
str = re.sub(r'----', lambda x: ('--' + next(seq) + ')--'), str)

print(str)
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/Va7RNX)

Comment: I got :
SyntaxError: invalid syntax for char = 'a':

Comment: remove the colon for the last line. `char = 'a'`

Comment: @YusufUMS Thanks, it seems it return the address of character:  'Today the --<generator object next_char at 0x0000021E9EE1EB48>)-- is cloudy, but there is no --<generator object next_char at 0x0000021E9EE1EB48>)--.'.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't calling the generator properly.  I updated the answer and added a runnable demo